# Finding out the stability of a complicated matricial differential equation about its fixed points

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose you have an equation ${{d\bf{A}}\over{dx}}= A B^\dagger A - B$,
 where A,B are $n\times n$ unitary matrices ; 
B is defined by $B_{ij}= -\frac{1}{2}\alpha_i\delta_{ij}A_{ij}$.

The expression isn't particularly important but note that the RHS is pretty complicated - B being a projection of A of sorts.

The fixed points of this equation are determined by equating the RHS to a zero matrix. I need to -

1. find out the fixed points to this system; for the $3\times 3$ case all of these may be guessed, except for one.
2. calculate the stabilities around these fixed points.
   EDIT: by "calculating stabilities about a fixed point" i mean the following -

(i) Obtain the fixed point(s) $A^*$ such that ${{d\bf{A}}\over{dx}}\vert_{A=A^*} = f(A^*)= 0$

(ii) if $A^*\mapsto A^*+\epsilon A_1$, the RHS changes, upto the first order in $\epsilon$ to a slightly larger function easily got at by the product rule of differentiation (note that the differential of $B$ is still the projection of $A_1$). Now one has to diagonalise this expression, to obtain choices of $A_1$ that satisfy the form $$ {{d\epsilon}\over{dx}}  = \mu \epsilon \vert_{\mbox{along $A_1$}}  $$ Note that any unitary transformation on A renders the concise relation between A and B moot.

Please suggest analytical approaches to tackle this problem.

EDIT: The fixed points of the equation ${{d\bf{A}}\over{dx}}= A B^\dagger A - A$ with the $\alpha_i$s set to one -  are - 
(i) The identity element of GL3 - 
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
(ii-iv) Cyclic Permutations of  - $$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

(v-vi) And the two cases - $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

(vii) Define $a\equiv \frac{1}{\sum_i \alpha_i^{-1}}$. The fixed point is -
$$
A_{ij} = -\frac{a}{\alpha_i}\delta_{ij} + \sqrt{( 1 - \frac{a}{\alpha_i})( 1 - \frac{a}{\alpha_j})}(1-\delta_{ij})
$$ 
Hope this helps!
 Code for the matrices are [here](http://pastie.org/3779648).

---

If you think you can help with a numerical method for this, visit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129911/generating-unitary-matrices-numerically-close-to-the-identity-element/129945#129945).

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense to me: if $A$ starts unitary, it won't remain unitary unless $\frac{d}{dx} (A^\dagger A) = 0$, and it doesn't look to me like that is the case here.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thats completely right. thus the product of any valid $A^*$ & $A_1$ has  to be anti-hermitian. The fact that $ U^\dagger U = 1$ is supposed to be a constraint on the evolution of the matrix $A$ with x, thus.

Comment: Another problem: unless I am mistaken, the unique fixed point is the diagonal matrix with entries $1/\alpha_i$ on the diagonal but your post alludes to multiple fixed points (that is, unless your $\delta$s are not Dirac deltas...).

Comment: No! of course not!! 
I will explain that part to edit the question as well. The html formatting isnt working down here.

Comment: $$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$ is not a unitary matrix.

Comment: sorry messed up the code - edited!

Comment: In case (ii)-(iv), $B=[[0,0,0]|[0,0,0]|[0,0,1]]$ hence $AB^\dagger A=B\ne A$. Case (v)-(vi) is even worse since $B=0$. (And please use @ if you want your comments to be notified to people.)

Comment: @Didier- sorry! SE noob alert! will use @ from now on <br/>
isnt the whole "point" of a fixed point (cant resist a comment here!) that ${\frac{dA}{dx}}=0$? Thereby $AB^\dagger A - B =0$?

Comment: @Didier terribly sorry! you were right the whole time. Editing the post again!! *trying to fit my hand in my mouth here*. The Equation is indeed 
${\frac{dA}{dx}}= AB^\dagger A - B$.

Comment: EDIT: added the seventh fixed point as well