# Generating $3\times 3$ Unitary Matrices close to the Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algorithms

Is there a way to generate uniformly spaced, or better still, to parametrise Unitary Matrices close to Identity. The solution is required primarily for $SU(3)$, but also in general for $SU(n)$.

It might be relevant that I am trying to optimise a function that takes in a unitary matrix as its argument. I am aware of the fact that $SU(n)$ matrices are exponentiated hermitian traceless generators. But that does not quite help me.

The outline of the problem that I am trying to solve is as follows -

I have an equation for the evolution of some unitary matrix. The evolution is constrained by the unitarity of the matrix - and i have the fixed points of this flow by generating the entire spectrum of $SU(3)$ matrices. But now i also have to find out the stability of these fixed points. I would prefer to use a systematic root finding type algorithm to accomplish this - which is where generating unitary matrices close to the identity comes in. 
After the initial brute force search in this space, i would also require increased resolution for bisection or Newton-Ralphson to work. I already have a way to generate a uniform distribution of unitary matrices *RANDOMLY* - refer [here](http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Random%20unitary%20%5Bpaper%5D.pdf). But I cannot use that for the root finding bit.

Hope the explanation helps! I have heard something about using two Householder transformations to do this, but didnt find anything to back it up! Please cite references if you don't have enough time. I will complete the answers and choose the one that leads me to the correct answer.

Comment: You can try generating an orthonormal base, which will then be the rows or columns of 
your unitary matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by *uniformly spaced*? Can't you use $\exp(-i\sum_j c_j H_j)$, where $H_j$ are the [Gell-Mann matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) to parametrize your matrices?

Comment: @draks hope the edit answers your question!

Comment: @auke the problem is to generate an ensemble of unitary matrices for root finding, not just one!

Comment: @Debanjan This seems to be almost an exact duplicate of your last question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129911/generating-unitary-matrices-numerically-close-to-the-identity-element/129945#129945), but with emphasis on $SU(3)$.  I have posted a modification of my answer from last time below.

Comment: @JimBelk Last time I emphasized on generating the matrices **randomly**. This time however, I want to run a root-finding algorithm on this space. These are indeed separate problems - however you might want to post this impoved answer to the post [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129911/generating-unitary-matrices-numerically-close-to-the-identity-element).

Comment: What's the function you are trying to optimise?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate random elements of $SU(3)$ close to the identity, it seems to me that the most logical approach would be to generate random elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, and then exponentiate them.

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ consists of all $3\times 3$ matrices $A$ with trace $0$ satisfying $A^\dagger = -A$.  Such a matrix can be written as
$$
A \;=\; \begin{bmatrix}ia_1 & b_1+ic_1 & b_2+ic_2 \\ -b_1+ic_1 & ia_2 & b_3+ic_3 \\ -b_2+ic_2 & -b_3+ic_3 & ia_3\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a_k,b_k,c_k$ are real and $a_1+a_2+a+3 = 0$.
Given a matrix $A\in\mathfrak{su}(3)$, the exponential $\exp(tA)$ is a unitary matrix for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

There is a standard inner product on $\mathfrak{su}(3)$, namely the negative of the [Killing form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form), which is invariant under the adjoint action.  This is given by the formula
$$
\langle A, A'\rangle = 12\sum_{k=1}^3 \left(\frac{1}{2}a_ka_k' + b_kb_k' + c_kc_k'\right)
$$
If we drop the factor of $12$, then we can easily find an orthonormal basis for $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ with eight elements:

$$
M_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}, \quad M_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
M_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\quad M_4=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\quad M_5=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
M_6=\begin{bmatrix}0 & i & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\quad M_7=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & i \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ i & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\quad M_8=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & i \\ 0 & i & 0\end{bmatrix},
$$
These are known as the [Gell-Mann matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices).

These eight matrices are like the standard basis of unit vectors for $\mathfrak{su}(3)$.  For example, if you want a random point on the sphere in $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ of radius $0.1$, the thing to do is to choose eight random coordinates $(x_1,\ldots,x_8)$ such that $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_8^2 = 0.1^2$, and then compute
$$
M \;=\; x_1M_1 + \cdots + x_8 M_8.
$$
This will be a random matrix at a distance of $0.1$ from the zero matrix in $\mathfrak{su}(3)$.

To get a random matrix in $SU(3)$, you simply exponentiate:
$$
\exp(M) \;=\; I + M + \frac{1}{2}M^2 + \frac{1}{3!}M^3 + \frac{1}{4!}M^4 + \cdots
$$
Then $\exp(M)$ will be a random matrix in $SU(3)$ at a distance of $0.1$ from the identity.

**Note:**  The only part I haven't explained yet is how to pick a random point $(x_1,\ldots,x_8)$ on the sphere of radius $0.1$ in $\mathbb{R}^8$.  Here is a standard algorithm:

1. Pick eight random numbers $(r_1,\ldots,r_8)$ between $-1$ and $1$.
2. If $r_1^2 + \cdots + r_8^2 > 1$, throw the numbers out and go back to step 1.  Keep picking until you choose one that satisfies $r_1^2 + \cdots + r_8^2 \leq 1$
3. Now we have a randomly chosen tuple $(r_1,\ldots,r_8)$ such that $r_1^2 + \cdots + r_8^2 \leq 1$.  Then let
   $$
   (x_1,\ldots,x_8) \;=\; \frac{0.1}{\sqrt{r_1^2+\cdots+r_8^2}}(r_1,\ldots,r_8)
   $$

Comment: in step 2 of choosing random point in $\mathbb{R}^8$, why do we have to throw out the numbers if the euclidean distance squared is > 1? Infact we wouldn't require step 2 at all.

Comment: @Debanjan If you don't throw out the tuples I suggest, the distribution won't be uniform on the sphere -- you will more often select points near the "corners" than near the sides.  See the following paper for a discussion of some other algorithms for picking points uniformly on a sphere: http://www-alg.ist.hokudai.ac.jp/~jan/randsphere.pdf.

Comment: @Debanjan By the way, if you want to generate a regular pattern of points on the 8-sphere (instead of random points), one possible method would be to use the vertices of a uniform 8-polytope (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_8-polytope).

Answer (score 1):

To parametrise unitary matrices close to the identity, we can use the fact that $SU(n)$ is a Lie group, of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(n)=\{A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})|A^*+A=0\}$, and that the exponential is a continuous mapping from $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ to $SU(n)$. Then the unitary matrices close to the identity are parametrized by the complex matrices satisfying $A^*+A=0$ that are close to zero.

To clarify, the exponential of a matrix is exactly the same as for a number : if $X$ is a matrix, $\exp(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n/n!$. Beware, though, that it is no longer true that $\exp(X+Y)=\exp(X)\exp(Y)$.

Comment: I might've not made myself clear the first time around! Please look at the edited question again.